# How do I map a kubectl create token to a callable API?

Tags: kubernetes

I need to execute [this operation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-token-em-) from my (.NET) application. How do I figure out which [k8s API to map](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/) this command to? Ideally, how do I use [the .NET SDK](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp) to make this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the API docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/#tokenrequest-v1-authentication-k8s-io

You can also inpsect what kubectl is doing by increasing the verbosity level: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-output-verbosity-and-debugging

> Kubectl verbosity is controlled with the -v or --v flags followed by an integer representing the log level. General Kubernetes logging conventions and the associated log levels are described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-instrumentation/logging.md).

Comment: I tried to use kubectl apply -f  token.yaml with this contents but it failed. 

`
apiVersion: authentication.k8s.io/v1
kind: TokenRequest
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
spec:
  audiences:
  - https://kubernetes.default.svc
  boundObjectRef: null
  expirationSeconds: 86400
`